# Trying to create a Pop Up "Modal" window with specific information inside

Tags: javascript, html

So I'm new to JavaScript so I'm unsure how to setup my code.

Before explaining its vital to look at my code - 
https://jsfiddle.net/avaris/bexn436s/

When right clicking inside a container a custom context menu pops up with a button, the button makes div (line 1) visible.

- I'm trying to make it so if you open the context menu by right clicking inside **container4** on line 38 (or any other container) whatever is in **ID** & **NAME** class will match **infoID**, **infoName** of div (line 1).
- All I'm looking for is advice or direction on possible solutions.

If opened by right clicking on "NAME4"

`<p class="NAME4">Valentine</p>` (line 41)

to

`<p class="infoName"></p>` (line 4)

The context menu script starts on line 61 and you determine in which element the context menu displays at line 144:

`var taskItemClassName = "container";`

-

I've tested everything but could not figure out a setup due to accessing the "info page" through the custom context menu made it way out of my expertise.

Any direction is all i'm looking for.

Tried to keep it short but if i explained poorly i'd love to give any more information.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `title` attribute for each of your components. If you hover over a particular item, you can get the intended value. Using JS you can add the `title` tag for each of your list components.